# ftp client multi user

Tags: sftp, users

I cannot find anything on point so here goes.   We need to ftp a single file three times a day.  Different users need to be able to share the client.

I tried WinSCP but it seems to store the configs on each user's profile.  I cannot put a shortcut to the site in the Public profile and allow any user logged into the workstation access to make it work.   WinSCP mentions copying the .ini file for each user but I am wondering if there is another option.  I don't want to have to try to remember to set this up when I get new users every year - amongst all the other setups we have to do.

Filezilla is another big name - will I have the same problem with that or will it allow multiple users access to the same app/site.

I really just need a very simple,free GUI interface which all users will be able to use without extra configuration.   And it only goes to a single sftp site.  I like the drag and drop offered by WinSCP - again simple.  Am I off base or is this possible?   My users are NOT all tech friendly so the fewer steps the better.   If there is a CLI way to do that I might even try and ask a tech to script a task to run automatically.

This is all brand new to me and I am doing lots of reading but am not even sure of the questions I need to ask yet!

Comment: Is the file the same filename or variant thereof? It might be easier to set up a script to perform the action to transfer the file and you can define the options required in parameters or options or batch file.

Answer (score 1):

I seem to have resolved my own question by a little trial and error.  I tried Filezilla but it didn't seem to want to share the config between users either.  There is an option while setting up both to allow only a local account or all users but this seems to only allow all users to use the app, not share a common config.

I will probably follow up on the scripting option - yes the file name is a slight variant every time it is created - same file name with the current timestamp appended.  I need to have it in place immediately so for now I copied the WinSCP.ini file from my AppData/Roaming folder to all the other users' AppData/Roaming profile folders.  I had several other users log on and it brought over the config data I had originally set up and allowed them to work with the correct site.